# chruby and ruby not available when I use sudo

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, chruby

I have installed chruby on ubuntu 14.04 and installed ruby-install and installed ruby 2.1.1 into /opt/rubies/

I have put the following into /etc/profile.d/chruby.sh

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] || [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]; then
  source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh
  chruby ruby-2.1.2
fi
```

I want all users to use that ruby and there is no default ruby package installed.

If I do chruby logged in as myself I get:

```
ubuntuserver ~: chruby
 * ruby-2.1.2
```

And ruby -v gives:

```
ubuntuserver ~: ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [i686-linux]
```

However if I do sudo chruby I get:

```
sudo: chruby: command not found
```

And if I do something like sudo rmate myfile.txt I get:

ubuntuserver ~: sudo rmate test.txt

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
```

I want to know how to make that ruby universal to users sessions jobs webserver etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question appears to have been answered on the [chruby wiki](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby/wiki/Sudo)

In essence you would have to get a root prompt and then run the chruby setup script , switch rubies then run your command ..

Alternatively you can use sudo chruby-exec ruby-n.n.n -- [command]

eg. If I run

```
sudo chruby-exec ruby-2.1.2 -- rmate test.txt
```

it does invoke textmate as required.